# Using OpenLayers 3 as react component

Tags: javascript, components, reactjs

I wonder whats best practice to manage OpenLayer3 map and layers as react components. Since only the map ultimately needs a `target` to be rendered in, the layers could be composed as react components, as well as the layers sources.
Are `Features` react children to the component or should we just use `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUpdate` to update features?

Comment: [This example](https://github.com/pka/ol3-react-example) might help you to get started, just in case you have not found it yet. However, I do not have much experience with it or React.js in general, so I cannot tell anything further about how good this approach works.

Comment: Thanks. I have switched to a very simple solution using mapbox now.

Answer (score 3):

One year later, I created this minimal wrapper
[react-openlayers](https://github.com/allenhwkim/react-openlayers).

Comment: Hi @allenhwkim, I've tried integrating this with my app but get the following error: a.V is not a function - could you advise? I followed the code example here: https://github.com/allenhwkim/react-openlayers/blob/master/app/layers/tile.tsx